# Display error message when user tabs out of field without entering data - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

i have an address directive which is used in two sections on the page - Pickup address, Delivery address

address.html.erb

```
<label>CONTACT</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input name="poc_name" class="form-control" placeholder="NAME" 
             id="pick_poc_name" ng-model="address.name"
             ng-disabled="isDisabled"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input name="poc_phone" class="form-control" placeholder="PHONE #"
             id="pick_poc_phone" ng-model="address.phone_number"
             ng-disabled="isDisabled"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

address,js.erb

```
'use strict';
angular.module('AngularBookManagement').directive('address', ['GeocodeService', 'MapService', function(GeocodeService, MapService) { 
    return {
       restrict: 'E', 
       scope: {
           name: '=',
           address: '=',
           index: '=',
           required: '@',
           isDisabled: '=',
       }, 
       templateUrl: '<%= asset_path('client/directives/address/address.html') %>', 
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
         scope.address = scope.address || { country: 'US'}; 
         scope.address.isValid = false; 
       }
    }
}]);
```

If the user tabs out of the name or phone field without entering anything, an error message should be displayed beneath each field.

**Edit: The same directive is used in the delivery section of the page as well. The validation should be only applied to pickup section and not delivery section.**

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state